# malloc causes the application to crash and show memory map

Tags: c, memory, crash, malloc

I'm working on a c application; when malloc is called the application crashes and shows the following output:

```
    ======= Backtrace: =========
    /lib64/libc.so.6[0x318f871ed1]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x7d)[0x318f8732ad]
    ./myprocess[0x40fbf7]
    ./myprocess[0x40daaa]
    ./myprocess[0x40d16a]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf4)[0x318f81d8b4]
    ./myprocess[0x40cfe9]
    ======= Memory map: ========
    00400000-004ff000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 37159057                           ./myprocess
    006ff000-00705000 rw-p 000ff000 fd:00 37159057                           ./myprocess
    00705000-008fe000 rw-p 00705000 00:00 0 
    1c265000-21717000 rw-p 1c265000 00:00 0 
    318f400000-318f41a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2490699                        /lib64/ld-2.5.so
    318f61a000-318f61b000 r--p 0001a000 fd:00 2490699                        /lib64/ld-2.5.so
    318f61b000-318f61c000 rw-p 0001b000 fd:00 2490699                        /lib64/ld-2.5.so
    318f800000-318f94a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2490700                        /lib64/libc-2.5.so
    318f94a000-318fb4a000 ---p 0014a000 fd:00 2490700                        /lib64/libc-2.5.so
    318fb4a000-318fb4e000 r--p 0014a000 fd:00 2490700                        /lib64/libc-2.5.so
    318fb4e000-318fb4f000 rw-p 0014e000 fd:00 2490700                        /lib64/libc-2.5.so
    318fb4f000-318fb54000 rw-p 318fb4f000 00:00 0 
    318fc00000-318fc02000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2490701                        /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
    318fc02000-318fe02000 ---p 00002000 fd:00 2490701                        /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
    318fe02000-318fe03000 r--p 00002000 fd:00 2490701                        /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
    318fe03000-318fe04000 rw-p 00003000 fd:00 2490701                        /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
    3190000000-3190082000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2490702                        /lib64/libm-2.5.so
    3190082000-3190281000 ---p 00082000 fd:00 2490702                        /lib64/libm-2.5.so
    3190281000-3190282000 r--p 00081000 fd:00 2490702                        /lib64/libm-2.5.so
    3190282000-3190283000 rw-p 00082000 fd:00 2490702                        /lib64/libm-2.5.so
    3190400000-3190415000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2490704                        /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
    3190415000-3190614000 ---p 00015000 fd:00 2490704                        /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
    3190614000-3190615000 r--p 00014000 fd:00 2490704                        /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
    3190615000-3190616000 rw-p 00015000 fd:00 2490704                        /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
    3190616000-319061a000 rw-p 3190616000 00:00 0 
    3190c00000-3190c07000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2490715                        /lib64/librt-2.5.so
    3190c07000-3190e07000 ---p 00007000 fd:00 2490715                        /lib64/librt-2.5.so
    3190e07000-3190e08000 r--p 00007000 fd:00 2490715                        /lib64/librt-2.5.so
    3190e08000-3190e09000 rw-p 00008000 fd:00 2490715                        /lib64/librt-2.5.so
    3193000000-3193015000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2490706                        /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
    3193015000-3193214000 ---p 00015000 fd:00 2490706                        /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
    3193214000-3193215000 r--p 00014000 fd:00 2490706                        /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
    3193215000-3193216000 rw-p 00015000 fd:00 2490706                        /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
    3193216000-3193218000 rw-p 3193216000 00:00 0 
    31a1a00000-31a1ae6000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 41193830                       /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8
    31a1ae6000-31a1ce5000 ---p 000e6000 fd:00 41193830                       /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8
    31a1ce5000-31a1ceb000 r--p 000e5000 fd:00 41193830                       /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8
    31a1ceb000-31a1cee000 rw-p 000eb000 fd:00 41193830                       /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8
    31a1cee000-31a1d00000 rw-p 31a1cee000 00:00 0 
    31a1e00000-31a1e0d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2490703                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080102.so.1
    31a1e0d000-31a200d000 ---p 0000d000 fd:00 2490703                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080102.so.1
    31a200d000-31a200e000 rw-p 0000d000 fd:00 2490703                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080102.so.1
    2b52154c7000-2b52154c9000 rw-p 2b52154c7000 00:00 0 
    2b52154c9000-2b5217aa0000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 41682874                   /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1
    2b5217aa0000-2b5217b9f000 ---p 025d7000 fd:00 41682874                   /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1
    2b5217b9f000
```

I'm pretty sure that the crash is happening because of malloc as I get the first line of log on the following piece of code, but I don't get the second one!!

```
SendLogMsg("first line of log");
p_my_structure = malloc(sizeof(my_structure));
SendEmsEvtBegstp("second line of log");
```

my_structure is defined as:

```
typedef struct __my_structure {
  char           cis  [12];
  char           Type;
  long long      oQty;
  long long      bQty;
  long long      sQty;
} my_structure;
```

EDIT:
BTW I have lots of free ram space on my machine when the process crashes!

Comment: Use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to find out where what is going wrong.  It is going to be hard to debug — the problem probably isn't in the code you've shown, and is probably caused by writing outside the bounds of an array and trashing control information used by `malloc()`.

Comment: I concur with that. If a call to `malloc` triggers a crash, you almost certainly corrupted the free-chain somewhere in your code, and a tool like valgrind is the bees knees for finding out where.